# What is the best way to navigate to a route using CX tab?

Tags: cxjs

I am using CX Tabs and would like to know what is the best way to navigate to a route within the CX app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use the Link widget and display it as a tab.

```
<Link baseClass="tab" mod="line" href="~/my-route">My Route</Link>
```